# html5 video not playing within Safari on Windows

Tags: html, video, safari, mp4

I'm trying to play a HTML5 video in safari on my local server but currently it isn't working properly. Here's the issue:

I have the code:

```
 <video width="580" height="340" controls>
     <source src="media/video/test.mp4" type="video/mp4">
     <source src="media/video/test.m4v" type="video/mp4">
     <source src="media/video/test.ogv" type="video/ogv">
     <source src="media/video/test.ogg" type="video/ogg">
     Your browser does not support the video tag.
 </video>
```

It simply says 'Your browser does not support the video tag.' when I view it on my local server through Safari. I made sure to add the mp4 etc MIME types in IIS and restarted including the WWW service.

The video plays fine when I view it via *direct* path in Safari and it works playing it within Chrome from the HTML.

Any ideas? Cheers!

**Update**

I didn't have Quicktime installed on my machine. Once installed, the HTML5 video played.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't have Quicktime installed on my machine. Once installed, the HTML5 video played.

Answer (score 0):

The version of safari you are using probably doesnt support the new html5 video tag,

you could try using a different type of player (shockwave youtube etc) to extend your browser support

Comment: It supported it, I just didn't have Quicktime installed on my machine. Once installed, it played the mp4. Thanks for you suggestion, anyway.