# html5 video not playing in safari 9

Tags: html, video, safari

I've been working on a project using html5 video tags to play uploaded videos.  So long as the video types were compatible it was working perfectly on Safari 8.  However, when I upgraded to safari 9, the tags stopped working.  I've set up a canPlayVideo function to react when a video can or cannot be loaded:

```
  function canPlayVideo( video, callback ) {
    video.oncanplay = function() { callback( true  ); };
    video.onerror   = function() { callback( false ); };
    video.addEventListener('error', function () { callback( false ) }, true);
  }
```

In Safari 8 my test .mp4 video when into video.oncanplay, and now on safari 9 it is going into the third option: 
`video.addEventListener('error', function () { callback( false ) }, true);`
If anyone has run into this issue and found a solution I'd love to hear what worked for you.  Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26139972/html5-video-not-playing-within-safari-on-windows?rq=1